# Why SmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials is ignored?

Tags: c#, smtp, credentials, smtpclient

I'm trying to send e-mails through a domain SMTP server which uses Integrated Windows Authentication. When explicitly specifying the credentials, everything works fine:

```
using (var client = new SmtpClient("<Server>"))
{
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("<User name>", "<Password>");
    client.EnableSsl = true;
    client.Send(...);
}
```

SMTP server logs show EHLO, STARTTLS, STARTTLS and EHLO, then AUTH, MAIL, etc.

When, on the other hand, default credentials are used:

```
using (var client = new SmtpClient("<Server>"))
{
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    client.EnableSsl = true;
    client.Send(...);
}
```

- the `SmtpException` is thrown, with a message “Failure sending mail.”;
- the inner `IOException` message is: “Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.”, and
- the inner-inner `SocketException` is: “An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host”.

SMTP server logs show EHLO, STARTTLS, STARTTLS and EHLO, then nothing.

The result is exactly the same (success for the first sample, failure for the second one) if the options are moved from source code to App.config `configuration/system.net/mailSettings/smtp/network`, and whenever the port number is specified or not.

Given that:

- [according to the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.usedefaultcredentials), `SmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials` “[g]ets or sets a Boolean value that controls whether the DefaultCredentials are sent with requests”, that
- “For a client-side application, [[`CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache.defaultcredentials.aspx)] are usually the Windows credentials (user name, password, and domain) of the user running the application”, and that
- the tested code is a Windows Forms client-side application running from the same account whose credentials were specified in the first sample above,

why the second sample fails, while the first one works?

---

On a forum [it was suggested](http://www.vistax64.com/net-general/156052-smtpclient-usedefaultcredentials-does-not-work-authenticated-sm.html#post723823) that the issue may be cause by SMTP server not supporting NTLM. By EHLOing the server, it appears that NTLM *is* supported, one of the response lines being `250-AUTH GSSAPI NTLM`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you actually have to specify the Credentials as well.
The UseDefaultCredentials is mere a flag telling the SMTPClient to use the Credentials provided to the Credentials property.

```
client.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

Here's some other things to try:

- Is this using .NET 4? [This Connect bug report](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/560365/system-net-mail-smtpclient-sending-mail-failed-through-server-with-integrated-windows-authentication#details) suggests issues with that version (although it's old and not resolved). You might try .NET v3.5 or v4.5
- Could it be a [cross zone issue](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ncl/thread/108a0786-7438-4c40-abcc-4020ed61b86f)?
- Try to specify the settings using your [app.config file instead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164240.aspx), see of that changes anything.

Comment: that makes sense because Credentials may be set to null if you don't do that

Comment: It helps. Partially. Now a new exception is thrown: “The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.3 Client was not authenticated.”

Comment: Have you specified EnableSsl ?

Comment: @Magnus - What are the credentials provided by SmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials ? Where do they come from ?

Comment: @blasto the SmtpClient does not provide any credentials. The UseDefaultCredentials is a simple boolean to tell the SmtpClient class to use the credentials you provide to it. You provide the credentials by assigning them to the .Credentials property, as shown in my answer. In my example I'm simply providing the default network credentials, but you could also do an explicit assignment, such as client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password)

Answer (score 12):

If *UseDefaultCredentials* is set to true, it does NOT mean use the values in the *Credentials* property. It means use the credentials of the "**currently logged on user**", which in the case of IIS web apps will usually be the app pool identity, and in the case of a Windows service is the identity of the service, and in the case of a desktop application, it's the identity of the user logged into Windows.

If *UseDefaultCredentials* is false (the default), the *Credentials* property will be used **if that property has a value set**, otherwise mail will be sent **anonymously**.

See the Microsoft document https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.usedefaultcredentials(v=vs.110).aspx (in the Remarks section).